# Merge data locally & offline in iOS app with RealmSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I’ve searched all over the internet for a tutorial on how to merge data in Realm DB! but actually I found nothing useful, Indeed no-one created a guide or tutorial on this topic.

I want to persist a book app contents locally in app but all the tutorials are on how to save the user "new data" in app and not about persisting and merging data in app such as a book app that have many chapters and includes long text materials that the user just want to read the contents(data) . .

I found out with Realm browser you can just edit the simulator's data and it seems there's no way to merge a Realm DB file with your app and finally publish it in App Store!

On the other hand I'm looking for a way to import long text data and some images to Realm and merge it with my app, so when user download the app, the user be able to see data in offline mode.

Thank you all for the time you're spending on this

Comment: Depends on the format of your book data. Which we know nothing about.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Book data format don't matters, actually I didn't decide which format I'll use yet .. , But just suppose it's the format you're familiar with and explain the solution please

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to bundle a populated Realm with an app which is documented here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#bundling-a-realm

Comment: @sellmeadog Thanks for your answer, I'd seen the documentations but that was not clear and not detailed . . , I'm still looking for a tutorial but it's not the first time that I'm facing closed doors at Stackoverflow . .